# Benchmarking under Windows

Tags: windows, benchmarking

Under most Unix-like systems, you can use the "time" command to execute a program and tell you how much space and time it used. Does anybody know of anything comparable for Windows?

(No, I don't particularly want to spend 6 months learning the Win32 API just for this...)

Answer (score 0):

From the command line (low resolution, possibly inaccurate): echo %date% %time%

Programmatically: QueryPerformanceCounter.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want something of the order of millisecond accuracy (which is comparable to what the linux/unix `time` would give you) then [timeGetTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is what you need.  It returns the number of milliseconds since the system was booted.  include `mmsystem.h` and link against `winmm.lib`.  However, all this would just give you a time value, you'd either need to put in a `system()` call in between or do something like dump the start time out to a file when called for the first time, and then read it the second time.

More pragmatic solutions, which may be more useful depending on your circumstances:

- Write a batch script to call the program you wish you benchmark and wrap it so that it writes to a file:

  echo "start" >> log.txt
  do_my_stuff.exe
  echo "stop" >> log.txt

  and then use a tool as the excellent [LogExpert](http://www.log-expert.de/) to look at the timestamps
- Install the cygwin tools and use the `time` that comes with that.  If you only need to do this on your own machine, and the benchmark program doesn't require complex setting up (command line parameters, environment variables, etc) then this may be the easiest approach.

Answer (score 0):

I use the 'time' utility in windows too. It comes with mingw+msys.